# how to add product.info.options.wrapper in custom extension magento

Tags: magento-1.9

My product page load from

```
diamonds\product\view\setting.phtml
```

How can I load custom option over here?

```
<diamonds_product_setting>
    <update handle="diamond_layout_update"/>
    <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="diamonds/product_view_setting" name="diamonds_product_ring_view" template="diamonds/product/view/setting.phtml">
            <block type="diamonds/filter_design" name="diamonds_filter_design" template="diamonds/filter/design.phtml"/>
            <block type="diamonds/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="diamonds/product/view/media.phtml">
            </block>                    
            <block type="diamonds/product_view_setting_mainstone" name="mainstone" template="diamonds/product/view/setting/mainstone.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</diamonds_product_setting>
```

Comment: Hello. Did you solve this question?

Comment: Oh..!!! Then, Did you use any other way for full fill this requirement?